# ¿Como consumir Api privada desde javascript utilizando fetch?

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Necesito consumir la API del siguiente sitio: https://rewards-api.egifter.com/index.html#section/Authentication

El problema esta al momento de hacer una llamada simple solo espero recibir el estatus 200 por parte del servidor para continuar con el desarrollo, estoy siguiendo parte de la documentacion pero obtengo el error 401. cabe mencionar que el script lo estoy llamando desde un simple html vacio solo espero recibir el mensaje que les menciono por consola para poder continuar con el desarrollo. Cualquier ayuda me vendria bien, no se si me estoy equivocando con la documentacion o el codigo espero me haya explicado. Esto es parte del codigo de javascript.

```
const API_URL = "URL_DE_LA_API"
let fetchData = {
   method: 'GET',
   mode: 'no-cors',
   //credentials: 'include',
   headers: { 
       //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
       //'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       //'Email': 'MAIL',
       //'AccessToken': 'XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX',
       'Authorization': 'Bearer XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX:MAIL_EXAMPLE@MAIL.COM' 
   }
}

fetch(API_URL, fetchData)
//.then( response => response.json() )
//.then( data => console.log(data) )
.then(res =>{
   if (res.ok){
      console.log('Success')
   } else{
     console.log('Not Successful')
   }
 })
 .catch(error => console.log('Error'))
```

**Este es el error que me muestra: GET https://stage-rewards-api.egifter.com/v1/Status net::ERR_ABORTED 401.**

**Update El error de los cors se arreglo de cierta forma agregando
mode: no-cors**
Access to fetch at 'https://rewards-api.egifter.com/v1/Orders' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
test.js:27

Cabe mencionar que el cors lo tengo activado desde la extencion que proporciona Google crome: Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin y ademas e intentantado con mandarles parametros en el header como se muestra en la parte comentada y obtengo otros errores.

[image: Error 401]

Answer (score 0):

Dado que es una petición para autenticación para usar la API y que el código de error es un 403 sugeriría cambiar la petición a POST ya que la mayoría de APIs requieren este método para autentificar de.
Podría ser también un error relacionado con las credenciales de acceso.

Por último en las opciones del fetch tendrás que cambiar `mode: no cors` por `mode: cors` ya que de la otra manera no tendrás acceso a la respuesta.

Si el error persiste cabe destacar que los errores de cors suelen ser del servidor y como está configurado el mismo.

Comment: agregando el `mode: no cors` me sigue apareciendo el mismo error que comente en la pregunta y en cuanto a las credenciales estas me las proveen desde el sistema de la plataforma, por lo que no se, si las estoy consumiendo como se debiera por eso mencionaba lo de los headers. y en si el error que me marca ahora que estoy consumiendo otra url en el mismo servidor de ellos es el 401. alguna ayuda con esto.